# vim on Windows -Turn syntax highlighting OFF

Tags: windows-7, vim, gvim

I have downloaded Vim 7.4 on Windows 7 64 bit, and would like to turn off syntax highlighting.

I have been using Vim for a long time on Unix, so I know to place "syntax off" in my vimrc. However, even though "syntax off" is in my vimrc, for some reason when I edit my vimrc the syntax highlighting is always on.

I have deleted every other vimrc on my system (listed in the output of :version) except for my $HOME\_vimrc, but the syntax highlighting is still there (even after creating new cmd's).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `$HOME\_vimrc` loaded at all? You can force vim to load a specific vimrc (or NONE) with the -u command line parameter.

You could try switching off the whole file type recognition:

```
filetype off
```

This will switch off filetype-related stuff, like syntax highlighting, setting options, plugins, see the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html).

If that doesn't do it, I guess you will need to go through the [Syntax loading procedure](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#syntax-loading) step-by-step and check what is wrong.

Comment: Turning filetype stuff off can disable more than just syntax highlighting.  It might be better just to use "`:syntax off`" instead.

Comment: Heptite - Using ":syntax off" does work once I'm viewing the file, it is just annoying that it isn't working from my vimrc

Comment: I tried the -u option, but the highlighting was still on. I know that the _vimrc is being loaded though, because other options (such as tabs to spaces and tab length = 2) are working. I noticed in my $HOME\_viminfo that after it displays my _vimrc under "REGISTERS", it displays the following: 
`""1 LINE  0\n
syntax off\n
"2  LINE  0` (real endlines - not the characters). I'm not sure if this helps.